# Why my component don't change even when render function it's being recalled? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component, react-state

Im changing a child component state from its parent using this method:

From parent:

```
this.changeBottomToolbar(newTool)
```

Method declared on Child's class

```
changeBottomToolbar(newToolbarName){
    this.setState({selectedToolbar: newToolbarName})
  }
```

It's state change and it re-renders as I check with the console.

The render it's a conditional render that uses a function to get what it should render

```
getBottomToolbar(){
    switch(this.state.selectedToolbar){
        case "SelectorAndText":
          console.log("Devolviendo el selector")
          return <TextBottomToolbar 
                    ref={this.bottomToolbarRef}

                    fontSizeUpdater    = {this.fontSizeUpdater}
                    fontColorUpdater   = {this.fontColorUpdater}
                    strokeColorUpdater = {this.strokeColorUpdater}
                    strokeSizeUpdater  = {this.strokeSizeUpdater}
                    fontFamilyUpdater  = {this.fontFamilyUpdater}
                    alignmentUpdater   = {this.alignmentUpdater}
                 />
        break
        case "FreeLine":
            console.log("Devolviendo el Line")
            return <LineBottomToolbar 
                    ref={this.bottomToolbarRef}

                    strokeColorUpdater = {this.strokeColorUpdater}
                    strokeSizeUpdater  = {this.strokeSizeUpdater}
                    shadowColorUpdater={this.shadowColorUpdater}
                    shadowSizeUpdater={this.shadowSizeUpdater}
                   />
        break
    }
}
```

And i call it on the render:

```
render(){
    const { classes } = this.props

    console.log(this.state.selectedToolbar)

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          this.getBottomToolbar()
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

As you can see in this image, the code it's been executed correctly and it returns the other component when the state it's changed

[image: s]

But the component ITS NOT CHANGING even tho the render it's been called again and it's state it's changing, im completely shocked, I have no clue on why this happens, please help!!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example using codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: Other than wondering why you are calling/updating child state from a parent, this might be one of those situations where providing a full component code example is necessary. A *running* codesandbox we could inspect and live debug in would be great. I suspect there's a state mutation somewhere but this is just a hunch. Can we see a more comprehensive code example?

Comment: It's a big project, I could try to do a sandbox with a simplified version, but in the meantime does anyone has some hints at least? im on a deadend right now

Comment: I uploaded all the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-moon-y3f8l?file=/meme/src/components/EditorComponents/BottomToolbar.js

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your sandbox, but it doesn't seem to render anything.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that i wrongly copy-pasted the import (facepalm)

This was the import I was doing so I thought it wasn't chaning

```
import TextBottomToolbar from './BottomToolbars/TextBottomToolbar'
import LineBottomToolbar from './BottomToolbars/TextBottomToolbar'
```

This corrected the problem:

```
import TextBottomToolbar from './BottomToolbars/TextBottomToolbar'
import LineBottomToolbar from './BottomToolbars/LineBottomToolbar '
```